# Adjacent cells depending of drop down menu

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have set up Data validation to have two different options (Option 1 and Option 2). What I want is: If I chose Option 1, I want the adjacent cell to be filed with formula +Sheet1!A1, but if I choose Option 2, then I would like for the same adjacent cell to look as it does not contain formula / or that it disappears.

Does anybody know how to get this?

Comment: That cell will always have a formula, but you can get it to output nothing. Is that acceptable? If not, you will need to go the VBA route.

Comment: Sure, that is acceptable. Can you please share how do it?

Comment: I already have one file with what I want (made by previous Project Owner), I've tried to search for the code in VBA, but it is empty

Comment: VBA is an advanced scripting language. If you need to go the VBA way, you have to program it from scratch. But I posted an answer on how to do it with a formula instead.

Answer (score 1):

Lets assume G3 has the cell with the data validation. G3 can only be "Option 1" or "Option 2". Depending on the content of G3, G4 will change.

The formula for G4 needs to be:

```
=if(G3="Option 1";Sheet1!A1;"")
```

Lets break it down.

```
=if(condition    ;true     ;false)

=if(             ;         ;     )    <- this is the formula itself
    G3="Option1"                      <- this is being evaluated.
                  Sheet1!A1           <- if the above condition evaluates to true
                                         the output of this formula is displayed
                                         in G4.
                            ""        <- if the above condition evaluates to false
                                         "" (aka nothing) is displayed in G4.
```

Comment: Thank you for your input! I understand the formula as it is pretty basic, but is it possible that, if I chose Option 2, the adjacent cell looks as it's been hidden / text coloured in white (the IF formula does not have to disappear)?

Comment: If you select option 2, then cell will look empty, why do you need to make it also white font??

Comment: You can alter the appearance of a cell, but you cannot alter the appearance of the formula in the formulabar. If you don't want to see the formula, VBA is required.

Comment: As Máté Juhász stated, if you use this formula and choose Option 2, then G4 should just look like an empty white cell; no additional work needed. However, if for some reason you're using some other color scheme for your spreadsheet and do need to adjust the appearance, you can use Conditional Formatting. Add a new rule that adds cell fill color or changes the font color, and apply it to just G4.

Comment: That's exactly what the formula does. Try it out and change the dropdown to see how it changes the adjacent cell.

Comment: Conditional formatting works! Thank you, I haven't thought of that. Cheers guys!